# R: reading csv files from a directory with zoo returns logical instead of time series

Tags: r, csv, stl, time-series, directory

I have two `csv` files in a folder. My files look like this:

```
file1.csv   file2.csv
1           10
2           20
3           30
4           40
5           50
6           60
7           70
```

I need to read these `csv` in and turn them into time series `ts` for further analysis with [`stl`](http://127.0.0.1:13086/library/stats/html/stl.html). My attempt:

```
dir<-"C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\MyFolder"
setwd(dir)

library(zoo)

listcsv<-dir(pattern="*.csv")
z1 <- read.zoo(file = listcsv[1], sep = ",", header = FALSE)
z2 <- read.zoo(file = listcsv[2], sep = ",", header = FALSE)
```

returns two elements that are of the type `logical` instead of `ts`:

```
> typeof(z1)
[1] "logical"
> typeof(z2)
[1] "logical"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` will return the data type of the atomic vector in your ts. To check if it is a `ts`, use  `class`.  Here's a reproducible example

```
# arbitrary time series
temp <- ts(1:5)

temp
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 5 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

typeof(temp)
[1] "integer"

class(temp)
[1] "ts"
```

Comment: My `class(z1)` returns `"zoo"` instead of `ts`. I think I am missing on something...

Comment: The concept is the same. Time series objects (ts) can easily be converted to `zoo` objects with `as.zoo`.

Answer (score 1):

A little research goes a long way.

To turn the `csv` files into time series, it seems like it is ok to do:

```
z3<-ts(z1)
z4<-ts(z2)
```

so that:

```
> z3
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 7 
Frequency = 1 

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
attr(,"index")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

and

```
> class(z3)
[1] "ts"
```

The same of course applies to `z4`.